# I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my pc and the pc hangs and does not restart more (translated)

Tags: boot-repair

Translated from google

My pc is an intel atom + Yes, it came with windows 7, formatted and installed Ubuntu 12.04, but the pc is unstable, it will not turn off properly and alone, appearing msg that there is no image signal, what to do?

---

Meu pc é um Sim+ intel aton, veio com o windows 7, formatei e instalei o ubuntu 12.04, mas o pc está instavel, ele não liga corretamente e desliga sozinho, aparecendo a msg que não ha sinal de imagem, o que fazer?

Comment: Hi welcome to askubuntu. Only allowed language is english. Use a translator. Read [FAQ]. / Oi bem-vindo ao askubuntu. Única língua permitida é o Inglês. Use um tradutor. Leia [FAQ]

Answer (score 0):

Translated from google

Do not know if it'll help much, but I was upgraded to the 10.04 and the 12.04, 12.04 unfortunately it is much heavier I'm dying to get back to the 10:04 just that I can not. Attempts to do the same.

---

Não sei se vou te ajudar muito, mas eu estava com o 10.04 e atualizei para o 12.04, infelizmente o 12.04 ele é bem mais pesado eu estou doido para conseguir voltar para o 10.04 só que não consigo. Tenta fazer o mesmo.